# Set JQuery UI modal dialog overlay background color dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

i want change the page packground color when the modal dialog loadui-widget-overlay and property `background-color`
when i set it with css it Works fine

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
   background-color: white;
}
```

[demo-with css](http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/gqque/)

but i want change it dynamically Because i have some modal dialog and i want change it only One of them 
i try use jquery but it not work

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'white');
```

[demo-with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/bniya_dev/dmGe5/)

why?

Answer (score 6):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dmGe5/1/)

**Problem with your code**

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'white');
```

you set `background` to `white` but the element with class `ui-widget-overlay` doesnot exist at that time in the DOM.

It works with `CSS` as whenever class  `ui-widget-overlay` is in DOM css rules will work.

But using `.css()` in `jQuery` puts `inline styling` so if the element is not present in DOM than no `inline styling` can be added.

**Solution**

After the Dialog is open you can perform this code as class `ui-widget-overlay` exists now.

**Working code**

```
$("#dialogDiv").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#dialogDiv").dialog('open');
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'white'); //write background color change code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/dmGe5/2/

`ui-widget-overlay` doesn't exist at that point in your code, so I moved it.